# WordPress can't find images with a @2x suffix?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a commercial theme and it seems to use a JS file to add a parallax scrolling effect to certain images at runtime. It was working fine a while ago and I didn't change anything. Now the parallax is not working.

I checked the console to find some 404 not found errors which are looking for the same images but with a "@2x" suffix. But before they were only looking up the original image names since those are the only names that exist in the library. What could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's probably a server issue. Clearing the browser cache seems to stop the retina images requests/responses.